# $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] returns different value on local and remote server

Tags: php, html

I am working on setting up a local development environment using MAMP and Coda 2.
I intend to work locally and publish my changes to my remote server.
I am finding that my relative links between pages do not work and I suspect it is because `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` which I am echoing in:

```
<base href="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']; ?> >
```

is returning different values depending if my `header.html` file is on the local or remote server.
What I have noticed is the containing site folder is included in the returned value ex: `folder/page_name.php`

I am not sure how to remedy this. Ultimately I want a solution that will work both locally and remotely

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please add some of your code segment which would be helpful to understand your question completely.

Comment: Formatted code and added a bit of whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

`$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` is the full (local) path of the script, so it's likely different on the server and it's not the best value to use when constructing urls.

Instead of using that value, I think you need `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` or even `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, but I will give it a shot.

`$_SERVER` is an array containing server and execution environment information. Basically, the list of environment variables provided by the server and defined on the user environment the web server is using for execution.

So if the variable `SCRIPT_FILENAME` is playing up, you can check its value on the server.

For linux based systems: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-read-and-set-environmental-and-shell-variables-on-a-linux-vps