# how pass php script_filename variable to /proc/(php_pid)/environ

Tags: php

i want to get result when i execute php code  ,
i hope the result include $_SERVER , or $_EVN variable (like below)
can i configure (nginx , apache , php conf) for the result?

i want to get script_filename value from /proc/{php_pid}/envrion not used getenv() php function

```
php code = <?php echo system("env"); ?>

= result 
    ORIG_PATH_TRANSLATED=/var/www/phpMyAdmin/php_test.php
    HTTP_USER_AGENT=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:106.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/106.0
    SERVER_PORT=80
    HTTP_ORIGIN=http://192.168.181.147
    HTTP_HOST=192.168.181.147
    REDIRECT_HANDLER=php5-cgi
    DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/
    SCRIPT_FILENAME=/var/www/phpMyAdmin/php_test.php
    REQUEST_URI=/phpMyAdmin/php_test.php
    SCRIPT_NAME=/phpMyAdmin/php_test.php
    HTTP_CONNECTION=keep-alive
    REMOTE_PORT=57672
    ORIG_SCRIPT_FILENAME=/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php
    PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
    PWD=/var/www/phpMyAdmin
    SERVER_ADMIN=webmaster@localhost
    REDIRECT_STATUS=200
    HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE=ko-KR,ko;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
    HTTP_REFERER=http://192.168.181.147/phpMyAdmin/php_test.php
    ORIG_SCRIPT_NAME=/cgi-bin/php
    HTTP_ACCEPT=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    REMOTE_ADDR=192.168.181.1
    SHLVL=1
    SERVER_NAME=192.168.181.147
    CONTENT_LENGTH=39
    SERVER_SOFTWARE=Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) DAV/2
    QUERY_STRING=
    SERVER_ADDR=192.168.181.147
    GATEWAY_INTERFACE=CGI/1.1
    HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS=1
    SERVER_PROTOCOL=HTTP/1.1
    HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING=gzip, deflate
    REDIRECT_URL=/phpMyAdmin/php_test.php
    CONTENT_TYPE=application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    REQUEST_METHOD=POST
    HTTP_COOKIE=pma_lang=en-utf-8; pma_charset=utf-8; pmaUser-1=xDvP6e96cQs%3D; pma_fontsize=82%25; phpMyAdmin=900c8e13524fea4a3a49c81422becfd88ef93531; php_testpass=angel; PHPSESSID=dd483809ce20d295b6fa0f32763fba60
    ORIG_PATH_INFO=/phpMyAdmin/php_test.php
    _=/usr/bin/env
```

Comment: You can use `$_SERVER` like this: `<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']; ?>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36877369/serverscript-filename-returns-different-value-on-local-and-remote-server

Comment: thaks for reply , but i must  get env variable via /proc/php_id/environ , not use php code +_+

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`getmypid()`](http://www.php.net/(getmypid)) to get the process id of the PHP script. Then you use this id to fetch the `/proc/{id}/environ` file.

```
<?php
$id = getmypid();
$path = "/proc/$id/environ";
$content = file_get_contents($path);
var_dump($path, $content);
```

This will generate content like this:

```
string(19) "/proc/18701/environ"
string(4720) "SHELL=/bin/bashSESSION_MANAGER=local/..."
```